# Xamarin Android NoSuchMethodError

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Android app live on the Play Store and am seeing a lot of NoSuchMethodError exceptions

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:    at
>   md5daa93411a9cc9943e09027d2340d0116.FixturesFragment.n_onResume
>   (Native Method)   at
>   md5daa93411a9cc9943e09027d2340d0116.FixturesFragment.onResume
>   (FixturesFragment.java:48)   at android.app.Fragment.performResume
>   (Fragment.java:2096)   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
>   (FragmentManager.java:928)   at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
>   (FragmentManager.java:1067)   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run
>   (BackStackRecord.java:834)   at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions
>   (FragmentManager.java:1462)   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run
>   (FragmentManager.java:447)   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback
>   (Handler.java:739)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:95)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:159)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5461)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:964)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:759)

Does anyone know what the cause of these errors are? Do I have to add a crash reporter to get more detailed stack traces in Xamarin?

Comment: Can you see the API level of the devices with this problem? It could be that you use something that needs a higher API level like permissions.

Comment: They are all on Android 5

Comment: You're probably requesting permissions at runtime and this doesn't work in Android versions before version 6.0. If you do so, put this around the code:

`if (((int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt) >= 23) {
}`

Comment: Thanks, it was down to me using GetDrawable.